# FabricJS Escape Double Quotes in JSON Text Object

Tags: json, canvas, escaping, fabricjs

I have built a graphics editor using FabricJS. I am using the toJSON() function to save the canvas via an AJAX call. I then reload the canvas using the loadFromJSON() function.

Everything works great until some a user adds a text object to the canvas that contains a double quote ("). The canvas saves just fine, but the quotation mark messes up the JSON string when I try to reload the canvas.

Here is an example of a text object that would cause the problem:

```
"text":"home comes with 42" TV"
```

I can escape the quote manually in the database and it solves the problem, but I can't seem to find a way to do this automatically. I think it needs to happen somewhere in the toJSON() process.

Any input is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use JSON.stringify to convert the fabric canvas to a string before saving it and that seems to escape embedded quotation marks properly. So when a user adds text to the fabric canvas that contains a quote mark, that quote mark is getting automatically escaped for me by JSON.stringify.

Comment: I am already using the stringify function and it does not escape the quotation marks.

Comment: Actually, you are correct. Stringify does escape the quotes. My problem was that I was using the Wordpress update_post_meta() function to save the data. Apparently that function uses stripslashes() when saving the data, thus removing the backslash from the quotes. I found the solution on this thread: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/129155/18300